# Comparing two countries using time series data

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I'm considering using time series data to compare Spain's and China's economic performance during various years of economic growth. However, I'm wondering if it's valid to compare them when they experienced economic growth in different years.

Regression is about the return to education, and I want to compare the recovery of education in China and Spain. I want to analyze the years 1960-2022 for China and 1960-2008 for Spain. These years are the years they experience economic growth. Or it is better to directly analyze the period of 1960-2022 for both of them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.